# Hyperlink Field with # in File Name

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink

Is there a trick to allow files with a `#` in their name to be opened via the hyperlink type field in Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not since `#` is part of the URL spec and that is interpreted as a fragment.

However, you could disable the default behaviour of the control that display the link and simply use the onclick event to open the link any way you want, using the `shell` command for instance.

Comment: Thank you. I decided to just remove the #'s from all files.